# Eloquent ORM: Define allowed model attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel's [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) ORM, is there a way to define a model's allowed attributes?

By default I can put any attributes into the model's constructor - but then I only get notified about the erroneous attribute names when I actually try to save the model to database.

Example code:

```
// this works although there is a typo in "lastname"
$user = new \App\User(['firstname' => 'foo', 'lastnam' => 'bar']);

// this errors out with an SQL error
$user->save();
```

---

So, is there a way to let Laravel automatically check if there are invalid keys in the request's input data?

Comment: @SteffenBrem and I highly recommend you to use Eloquent instead of Doctrine in Laravel projects. )

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Eloquent is okay for demos or prototypes, but for any other case Doctrine is superior. Eloquent violates a lot of programming principles and they do that to make it "easier" (we can argue about that) to work with. I am just giving an advice for beginners so they don't have to take the long path on their programming journey.

Comment: @SteffenBrem Laravel itself violates a lot of programming principles. That's why it's so convinient for real projects. ) Symfony is another great framework for those who prefer honoring all known programming principles over convinience and higher delevopment speed.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Indeed! Glad you said that. I am trying to encourage people to lean more to those principles and working with projects that adhere to those is a good way to begin understanding them. It's just so easy to learn yourself those bad practises in frameworks like Laravel and that won't do anyone any good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would like to prevent not only filling not allowed attributes using `fill()` method but also directly setting them, like `$model->foo = 'bar'`, then you got to override `Model::setAttribute()` method.

Best to do it in a custom base Model that extends Eloquent. So in `app/Model.php`:

```
namespace App;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Model extends Eloquent
{
    // this should be actually defined in each sub-model
    protected $allowed = ['firstname', 'lastname'];

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        // this way we can allow some attributes by default
        $allowed = array_merge($this->allowed, ['id']);

        if (! in_array($key, $allowed)) {
            throw new Exception("Not allowed attribute '$key'.");
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Then in the models that should not allow invalid attributes you can extend this base model:

```
use App\Model;

class User extends Model
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this can be done natively. I think Laravel is intentionally permissive in that sense, and I personally don't mind having a SQL error instead of an Eloquent one if I make a mistake setting attributes somewhere.

That being said, it's not hard to customize your Models to fail when non-existing attributes are set:

```
// User.php

protected $fillable = [
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
];

public function fill(array $attributes)
{
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($key, $this->getFillable())) {
            throw new \Exception("Attribute [{$key}] is not fillable.");
        }
    }

    return parent::fill($attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you're adding attributes like this, Laravel [uses](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L290) the [`fill()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L441) method which is part of [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature:

```
if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
    $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
} elseif ($totallyGuarded) {
    throw new MassAssignmentException($key);
}
```

So, to make it work add all allowed values you want to be saved to [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) array :

```
$fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not tell me about invalid attributes - they are silently discarded because `fillableFromArray` is used.

Comment: @cweiske you should validate input data manually. You don't want to get SQL error or something, you want to know if some field is empty before you're trying to persist the data.

Answer (score 4):

You could override the model constructor and validate there:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
//...

public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($this->table);

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        if (! in_array($attribute, $columns)) {
            // not allowed
        }
    }

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best approach, although you could also combine it a little bit with [Paul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41098491/2053165) and only write it once in a base model class if you didn't want to copy-paste this into every model you have. This is essentially validating your own code so you can find typos, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use laravel exists:column validation rule for each input.
Please check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists

OR

You can make helper for this purpose

$table is table name

```
function validateInputColumns($table, array $inputs) 
{
    $unknownCols = null;

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($inputs as $key => $val) {
        if (! Schema::hasColumn($table, $key)) {
            $unknownCols[$i] = $key;

            $i++;
        }
    }

    return is_null($unknownCols) ? true : $unknownCols;
}
```

It will return the unknown column list in array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events) might be of help to you.
You could then compare the input array to the fillable array.